# Update checkbox em array

Tags: php

Me deparei com uma situação que não estou conseguindo contornar.

Preciso atualizar um campo em banco MySQL, onde a exibição dele é um *checkbox*.

Vou tentar exemplificar:

Uma busca traz uma série de registros, onde, após eu marcar os checkbox e clicar no botão **"Confirmar Conferência"**, todos os registros listados nessa página devem ser atualizados de acordo com o `checkbox` marcado, ou seja, apenas o campo do checkbox sera atualizado. Segue imagem mostrando a tela que já existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da minha página é esse:

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="top" class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Conferência do Depósito</h3>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /#top -->
    </br>

    <div id="conf_deposito" class="row">    
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered " width="100%" id="tabela_datatables">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Conferir</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Tombamento</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php
            //Verifica se já existem registros com a mesma data do sistema. Se não existir, executa a cópia da tabela.
            $sis_data = date("Y/m/d");
            $unic = "SELECT * FROM conf_material WHERE data = '$sis_data'";
            $unic = $pdo->query($unic);
            if($unic->rowCount() < 1) {

            //Ao carregar a página, executa uma cópia dos registros para conferência.
            $cop = "INSERT INTO conf_material  (nome, tombamento, quantidade, local) SELECT nome, tombamento, quantidade, local FROM lista_geral WHERE local = 'deposito'";
            $cop = $pdo->query($cop);

            //Atualiza o campo de data para o data do dia.
            $atualiza_data = "UPDATE conf_material SET data = '$sis_data' WHERE data = '0000-00-00'";
            $atualiza_data = $pdo->query($atualiza_data);
            }

            if(isset($_POST['nome']) && empty($_POST['nome']) == false) {
                $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
                $tombamento = addslashes($_POST['tombamento']);
                $quantidade = addslashes($_POST['quantidade']);
                $conferir = addslashes($_POST['conferir']);

                $sql = "UPDATE conf_material SET conferir = '$check_confirm'";
                $pdo->query($sql);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM conf_material WHERE local = 'Deposito' AND data = '$sis_data'";
            $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
            if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($sql -> fetchAll() as $conf_deposito) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="actions">
                        <input type='checkbox' id="check_confirm" name="check_confirm" value="1" class='btn btn-success btn-xs' data- data-toggle="modal"></button></a>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['nome']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['tombamento']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['quantidade']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?> <!-- Fecha foreach -->
            <?php } ?> <!-- Modal de IF rowcount -->    

    <form method="POST">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmar Conferência" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a href="lista_geral.php" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</a>
    </div>
</form>

        </tbody>
    </table>

<!-- Rodapé -->
<?php require "rodape.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como faço isso?

Comment: 1 - os checkbox estão fora do formulário - 2 os inputs tem value = 1 sempre? 3 - No atributo name, no final de seu nome, deve colocar colchetes, indicando que poderá ser enviado mais de um valor para o mesmo campo. no lado do servidor, será enviado um array com esses elementos. 4 - Faltando action no form (manda para a pagina atual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>O seu script mais parece um enigma com um jogo dos sete erros! :)</sub>

**Considerações iniciais**

A tag form deve envolver todos os campos a serem submetidos:

```
<form method="POST">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered " width="100%" id="tabela_datatables">
............
............
</table>
</form>
```

No `foreach ($sql -> fetchAll() as $conf_deposito) {`

deve  assim:

```
<tr>
  <td class="actions">
    <input type='checkbox' id="check_confirm" name="check_confirm[]" value="<?php echo $conf_deposito['id'] ?>" class='btn btn-success btn-xs' data- data-toggle="modal">
  </td>
```

> No atributo name, no final de seu nome, deve colocar colchetes, indicando que poderá ser enviado mais de um valor para o mesmo campo. No lado do servidor, será enviado um array com esses elementos.

**Código final - comentários no próprio código**

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="top" class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Conferência do Depósito  </h3>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /#top -->

    <?php

        //**********conexão*********
                $hostname="localhost";  
                $username="USUARIO";  
                $password="SENHA";  
                $db = "NOME_DB";  
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
        //**********conexão*********                

            $sis_data = date("Y/m/d");

            //quantidade de registros retornados
            $Registros = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conf_material WHERE local = 'Deposito' AND data = '$sis_data'");
            $total = $Registros->fetchColumn();

            //para uso no formulário Resultados Por Pagina
            $quarto=(int)($total/4);

            if($_POST["resultadosPorPagina"]){
                $resultadosPorPagina=$_POST["resultadosPorPagina"];
            }else{
                $resultadosPorPagina=(2*$quarto);
            }

    ?>

    </br>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <select name="resultadosPorPagina" size="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>Resultados Por Pagina</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $quarto ?>"><?php echo $quarto ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo 2*$quarto ?>"><?php echo 2*$quarto ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo 3*$quarto ?>"><?php echo 3*$quarto ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $total ?>" >Todos</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="conf_deposito" class="row">    
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered " width="650" id="tabela_datatables">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100px"></td>
                    <td width="200px">Nome</td>
                    <td width="50px">Conferir</td>
                    <td width="200px">Tombamento</td>
                    <td width="100px">Quant</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 

            //Verifica se já existem registros com a mesma data do sistema. Se não existir, executa a cópia da tabela.
            $sis_data = date("Y/m/d");
            $unic = "SELECT * FROM conf_material WHERE data = '$sis_data'";
            $unic = $pdo->query($unic);
            if($unic->rowCount() < 1) {

            //Ao carregar a página, executa uma cópia dos registros para conferência.
            $cop = "INSERT INTO conf_material  (nome, tombamento, quantidade, local) SELECT nome, tombamento, quantidade, local FROM lista_geral WHERE local = 'deposito'";
            $cop = $pdo->query($cop);

            //Atualiza o campo de data para o data do dia.
            $atualiza_data = "UPDATE conf_material SET data = '$sis_data' WHERE data = '0000-00-00'";
            $atualiza_data = $pdo->query($atualiza_data);
            }

            if(isset($_POST['check_confirm']) && empty($_POST['check_confirm']) == false) {

                $check_confirm = $_POST['check_confirm'];

                //vindo do input hidden que está antes da tag de fechamento form no final da pagina
                $ids=$_POST['arrayId'];
                $explodeIds = explode(',', $ids);

                $count=count($check_confirm);

                //aqui são feitos os UPDATES na coluna conferir com valor = 1 dos checkboxes que foram marcados
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 

                    $check = $check_confirm[$i];

                     $sql = "UPDATE conf_material SET conferir='1' WHERE id='$check'"; 
                     $pdo->query($sql);

                //aqui são retirados os ids do array que serviram para a clausula WHERE do update acima
                        $key = array_search($check, $explodeIds);
                        if($key!==false){
                            unset($explodeIds[$key]);
                        }

                }

                //aqui são feitos os UPDATES na coluna conferir com valor = 0 cujo checkboxes não foram marcados
                foreach ($explodeIds as $val) { 
                    $sql = "UPDATE conf_material SET conferir='0' WHERE id='$val'"; 
                     $pdo->query($sql);
                }

            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM conf_material WHERE local = 'Deposito' AND data = '$sis_data' limit $resultadosPorPagina";
            $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
            if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {

                //este array conterá os ids que figuram nos checkboxes
                $listStr = Array();

                foreach ($sql -> fetchAll() as $conf_deposito) { 

                    $listStr[] = $conf_deposito["id"];

             ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="actions">

                        <!--os values destes checkboxes são os ids que servirão para a clausula WHERE dos UPDATES-->
                        <input type='checkbox' id="check_confirm" name="check_confirm[]" value="<?php echo $conf_deposito['id'] ?>" class='btn btn-success btn-xs' data- data-toggle="modal">

                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['nome']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['conferir']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['tombamento']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $conf_deposito['quantidade']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?> <!-- Fecha foreach -->
            <?php } ?> <!-- Modal de IF rowcount -->    

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmar Conferência" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <!--a href="lista_geral.php" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</a--><br>
      </div>
    </div>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- input cujo value é a relação de ids constantes nos checkbox desta página -->
    <?php
       $listStr = implode(",",$listStr);
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="arrayId" value="<?php echo $listStr; ?>">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> Esse script funciona de acordo com uma `resposta` do autor

"clicasse no botão "Confirmar Conferência", somente o campo do chackbox - **de todos os registros** - seriam atualizados ao mesmo tempo (**com 0 ou 1, dependendo se o campo foi marcado ou não**)."

Comment: Leo, infelizmente o update não funcionou. Nada é inserido no campo `conferir`. :/ Ademais, o script de paginação não é necessário, mas ficará guardado para uma eventual necessidade. Consegue me ajudar update?

Comment: @emersonsbr vou testar realizando as querys

Comment: Ok, Leo! O Script funcionou, muito obrigado! Uma última pergunta, é possível rodar o script sem que o campo `nome` esteja definido como `<input type="text">`, ou seja, apenas utilizando `<?php echo $conf_deposito['nome']; ?>`??? Vou me atentar para a organização das perguntas e comentários.

Comment: @emersonsbr Sim, porém essa validação `if(isset($_POST['nome']) && empty($_POST['nome']) == false) {` deve ser trocada por outra que não dependa desse `$_POST['nome']`  Pode usar `if(isset($_POST['check_confirm']) && empty($_POST['check_confirm']) == false) {`

Comment: Agradeço aos colegas por disporem de um tempo para me ajudar, em especial, ao @LeoCaracciolo que solucionou minha dúvida. Darei os devidos créditos. Até a próxima!

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, Leo Caracciolo...

Desculpe a bagunça... Vou tentar explicar melhor o que preciso:

Tenho um select que traz uma série de registros. Eis que, nesses registros eu preciso aplicar uma flag (numero 1 no bd) e que, na minha cabeça, a melhor maneira seria utilizando um campo checkbox, para que, quando o usuário marcasse o checkbox e, em seguida, clicasse no botão "Confirmar Conferência", somente o campo do chackbox - de todos os registros - seriam atualizados ao mesmo tempo (com 0 ou 1, dependendo se o campo foi marcado ou não). Espero ter explicado melhor...
Grato pela ajuda!
To quebrando a cabeça aqui também, enquanto aguardo!